# django - get() returned more than one Phones -- it returned 4

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working on a small api in django.
I have 2 models/tables
1st user , 2nd phones

```
_____________
**models.py**
_____________

class Users(models.Model):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10 , default='BLOCKED')
    address = models.TextField(null=False,default=None)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class Phones(models.Model):
    phoneId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=None)
    userId = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    numbers = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=True)
    phonesCountryCode = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'phones'
```

I have written the code to get data from json object. the json object looks like this

```
______________
**json input**
______________

{
      "name": "abc",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "address": "xyz",
      "phones": [
        {
          "numbers": {
            "numbers": "23378",
            "phonesCountryCode": "+91"
          }
        },
        {
          "numbers": {
            "numbers": "12390",
            "phonesCountryCode": "+91"
          }
        },
        {
          "numbers": {
            "numbers": "7890",
            "phonesCountryCode": "+91"
          }
        },
        {
          "numbers": {
            "numbers": "45221",
            "phonesCountryCode": "+91"
          }
        }
]
}
```

inserting data into database works fine.
but when i want to update the data it is giving me the error
I have multiple data in the database that is why getting multiple data error if using get() and if use filter() it gives me error that no attribute _meta.
I am not finding any answer a help will be very appreciated.

```
____________
**views.py**
____________

@api_view(['PUT'])
def ListUpdate(request,pk):
    data = request.data
    name =data['name']
    status=data['status']
    address=data['address']
    user= Users.objects.get(userId=pk)
    print(location)
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(data={"name": name,"status": status, "address": address},instance=user)
    usrid= Users.objects.latest('userId').userId
    Useriiid= usrid
    if location_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        location_serializer.save()
    
    
    
    
    for person in data['phones']:
        numbers=person['number']['number']
        phonesCountryCode=person['number']['countryCode']
        phn = Phones.objects.get(userId= pk)
        phone_serializer = PhoneSerializer(instance=phn,data={"userId":Useriiid,"numbers":numbers,"phonesCountryCode":phonesCountryCode})
        if phone_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            phone_serializer.save()
    return Response({'status': 'Success'})
```

I tried the code it worked if phones table has only single data
i.e has the unique id userId.

Comment: Please use a real ForeignKey to link your models, not an `IntegerField`!

Comment: Either way, yes, `.get()` is meant to only get a single object. You get an exception if there are multiple objects returned from the query. What do you expect your code to do? Should it just always add new phones? Should it remove all of the user's phone numbers and replace them with whatever is `PUT`?

Comment: Also: model names should be singular (since each model instance indeed represents a single User or a Phone, not a group of Users or Phones).

Comment: I want to remove all existing values and update with new values

Answer (score 1):

Between everything else that's, shall we say, non-idiomatic about your code, I think you want something along the lines of this.

```
def ListUpdate(request, pk):
    data = request.data.copy()  # Grab a shallow copy of the data, so...
    phones = data.pop("phones")  # ... we can remove the phones...
    user = Users.objects.get(userId=pk)
    with transaction.atomic():  # do all changes or none of them
        # ... and use the rest of the data as-is here in `data`
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=data, instance=user) 
        user_serializer.save()  # update user info
        Phones.objects.filter(userId=user.pk).delete()  # wipe out all phones for the user
        for phone in phones:  # loop over the phones data, validate & save
            phone_serializer = PhoneSerializer(data=phone)
            if phone_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                phone_serializer.save(userId=user.pk)
    return Response({"status": "Success"})
```

As said, though, you really should look into how foreign keys in Django work instead of relying on integer fields for them.